Getting a list from many-to-many column
I have the following data structure with the many-to-many relationship:
things_tags = Table("things_to_tags", Base.metadata,
                    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                    Column('thing_id', Integer, ForeignKey('things_table.id')),
                    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags_table.id')),
                   )

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'things_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)    
    title = Column(String)    
    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary = things_tags, back_populates='things')

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags_table'    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)    
    things = relationship("Thing", secondary = things_tags)

And I would like to retrieve all "things" from the database with their associated "tags" in the format:
[
 (thing1, [tag2, tag5, tag6]),
 (thing2, [tag1, tag3]),
 ...
]

I tried to query the database with
session.execute(select(Thing.title,Tag.name).join(Thing.tags)).all()

But this gives me the result in the format:
[(thing1, tag2),
 (thing1, tag5),
 (thing1, tag6),
 (thing2, tag1),
 (thing2, tag3),
...
]

I almost managed to obtain the desired result with
for x in session.query( Thing ).all():
    print(x.title, x.tags)

But, if I understand correctly, this is not the proper way of doing it. First, query() is being deprecated. Second, every time I invoke x.title or x.tags, the database is being connected again. So, for a large database, this would result in many many connections to the database.
I am trying to find the method to achieve what I want for hours and hours now, but cannot seam to find any good pointers to how to do that.

Are you targetting a particular RDBMS?

Sorry, I am really not an expert in either sql or databases in general. It is the first time I read this acronym RDBMS. Even a quick look at Wikipedia does not  help much in replying to your question. My real database structure I am working with is much larger than the one provided in the question, of course. For the question I just extracted the relevant part. What I want is to extract all "things" from the database with the associated "tags" for each of them and do it in the most efficient way.

What I meant was, are you targetting a specific database type, for example, SQLite, Oracle, MySQL etc.?

I am using SQLite. But I thought that this kind of a query is agnostic to the specific database type.

The solution that you have accepted is db-agnostic and is perfectly fine. However some databases provide specific functions or syntax may be helpful.

I see. Thank you for the comment. I will keep this in mind as I learn more about databases.

I think u can try this code once
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import selectinload
query = select(Thing).options(selectinload(Thing.tags))
result = session.execute(query).scalars().all()
formatted_result = [(thing, thing.tags) for thing in result]

This will load all the things and their tags and also return the data in a way u desire.[Avoid N+1 query prob]

Thanks a lot Debmalya Das! This seams to have worked.

Happy to help ..
